# Where exactly is the default partition decided in kafka producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to grep through source code and all I am able to find is

`/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.10/0.9.0.2/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.jar!/kafka/javaapi/producer/Producer.class`

```
public void send(List<KeyedMessage<K, V>> messages) {
   this.underlying().send(scala.collection.JavaConversions..MODULE$.asScalaBuffer(messages).toSeq());
}
```

which calls

`/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.10/0.9.0.2/kafka_2.10-0.9.0.2.jar!/kafka/producer/Producer.class`

```
public void send(Seq<KeyedMessage<K, V>> messages) {
    synchronized(this.lock()) {
        if(this.hasShutdown().get()) {
            throw new ProducerClosedException();
        } else {
            this.recordStats(messages);
            boolean var3 = this.sync();
            BoxedUnit var4;
            if(var3) {
                this.eventHandler().handle(messages);
                var4 = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
            } else {
                if(var3) {
                    throw new MatchError(BoxesRunTime.boxToBoolean(var3));
                }

                this.asyncSend(messages);
                var4 = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
            }

            BoxedUnit var10000 = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        }
    }
}
```

Its quite confusing because I am expecting both the `send` function to accept partition id from [default partition](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java) like

```
public void send(List<KeyedMessage<K, V>> messages, int partition id)
```

or somehow call the default partition to get the partition id in the `send` method definition

But I don't see the partition id used anywhere.

Can someone point me a direction on where to look for where the partition is decided?

Is it before we call `producer.send`?

Comment: It's within the send method that the Partitioner is decided, but you're looking at the old Producer API, not the new one (Kafka 0.10.x)

Comment: `asyncSend` is where you should be looking for this particular code

Comment: @cricket_007 unfortunately we are using kafka version `<kafka.version>0.9.0.2</kafka.version>`

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the old API, that logic is [in the EventHandler](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.9.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/producer/async/DefaultEventHandler.scala#L153), which is [called by the send method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.9.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/producer/Producer.scala#L77)

---

For the newer clients, [you can see it in the doSend method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L813)

```
 int partition = partition(record, serializedKey, serializedValue, cluster);
 tp = new TopicPartition(record.topic(), partition);
```

[The partitioner class is loaded from the properties given to the Producer](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L358). If not defined, it's the default